# How to create typings declaration for javascript module exported as a global?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I wrote a library written in typescript and I use webpack to bundle it into a single, minified js file that exports the library as one global variable. I want to distribute these typings for the developers on my team. They are not typescript users so they would be importing the library itself via a `<script src="...">` tag and they would import the typings using the triple slash reference directive `/// <reference path="..." />` or [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) or something similar.

The question is then:

**How do I enable typings (i.e., the intellisense) for my library for the js developers that use vs code?** How do I declare that there is one global variable that exports the values that my entry point does?

I have enabled the [`declarationDir` and `declartion` compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to create create the declaration files (`*.d.ts`) for all my typescript source files but these declarations don't declare that there is a global variable available with the methods.

I've tried manually creating a `index.d.ts` declaration in the same folder where the bundle and minified `index.js` file is but I can't get it to work.

Here is what I tried:

```
import * as myModule from './typings/src/';

declare module TheGlobalVariable {
    // how do I declare that `TheGlobalVariable` has the same methods
    // as `myModule` exports?
    export = myModule; // doesn't work
}
```

where `./typings/src/index.d.ts` is the generated declaration file for the entry point of this library and `TheGlobalVariable` is the name of the global variables webpack exports.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I figured it out.

In the same folder where my bundled js library file is (`index.js`), I added a file `index.d.ts`. Here is that file:

```
export * from './src';
export as namespace OntologyStore;
```

**The key enabler is the `export as ...`.**

Refer to this [module template](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) and [this documentation on library structures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html).

Also change the webpack `libraryTarget` to `'umd'`. UMD modules check to see if there is a module loader and if there isn't it will export to a global. Also I didn't have to use the `declaration` or `declarationDir` compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure, https://github.com/botika/typescript-package.
Only follow a README.md